# flask -- how to get around limitation that app.route / app.add_view_rule doesn't work with closures?

Tags: python, flask

Apparently, Flask's `app.route` / `app.add_url_rule` doesn't work with closures. For example, creating a basic app with,

```
for name in ('/hi', '/bye'):
    app.add_url_rule(name, view_func=lambda: name)
```

and querying it,

```
dev:~/pg/yelp-main> curl localhost:9113/hi
/bye
```

shows that it doesn't work with closures. What's the easiest way to work around this? Can I force Python to actually create two functions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't actually created a closure in your code that preserves the *value* of `name`:

```
view_func=lambda: name  # <- points at the *symbol*, which holds the *last* value
# in the case of a loop
```

To preserve the *value* you need to pass the value into the closure:

```
view_maker = lambda name: (lambda: name)

for name in ('/hi', '/bye'):
    endpoint = name.replace("/", "")
    app.add_url_rule(name, view_func=view_maker(name), endpoint=endpoint)
```

**EDIT:** In addition, you'll need to ensure that each time you register a function using `add_url_rule` you either specify an `endpoint` or ensure each function has a unique `__name__` (since Flask actually stores the routes in a dictionary keyed on the `endpoint`, which it derives from the function's `__name__` if no other is provided).  Otherwise, your second view will overwrite your first one.

You *may* want to look into Flask's [class-based Views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#class-based-views) - they may make it easier to build the dynamics you are looking for (although closures and classes are quite similar [in that both are the poor man's substitute for the other]).

Comment: Um, apparently not -- you can easily create the scaffolding to test it yourself [ http://pastebin.com/6Zt1iCGs ]. This still responds "/bye" when given the URI "/hi". I solved the problem by just using request.uri, but it felt a little ugly.

Comment: Didn't mean to be rude ... meant to add "thanks anyway, though" :)

Comment: *Chuckles* @gatoatigrado - no offense meant, none taken!  I've updated my answer (the closure *does* work, but Flask overwrites the function stored in `url_mapper` because both functions have the same `__name__`).  The new version works :-)

Comment: @gatoatigrado - actually I mispoke about not being able to register the same function more than once without changing its `__name__` - see my updated answer for more information about the `endpoint` keyword argument.